# Cannot set Column 'name'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, datatable

I have a table with 5 columns.

They are:

**fItemID** - Int IDENTITY Primary Key
**fItemName** - varchar(50)
**fItemType** - varchar(50)
**fItemModel** - varchar(50)
**fItemWeight** - int

When I try to add data to the table, using a DataGridView, I have no problems as long as I keep the values under 10 characters, but when I try to add 11 or more, I get an error message on three of the columns.

For **fItemName** and **fItemType**, I get:

> *Cannot set Column 'name'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column.*

When I try to add more then 10 characters to **fItemWeight**, I get:

> *System.FormatException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32. ---> System.OverFlowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.*

I have no idea why I am getting these errors, as adding info to **fItemModel** works perfectly.

As usual, I am using VS2013 Ultimate and VB.Net.

---

The following is all the code for the form:

```
Public Class frmBOMNonSteel

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItemsQuery' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblItemsQueryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItemsQuery)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblItemsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblItemsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblItemsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TblItemsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems)
        Me.txtJobNumber.Text = frmParent.ToolStripTextBox1.Text

        With FItemTypeComboBox
            .DataSource = DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItemsQuery
            .ValueMember = "fItemType"
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub SteelToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SteelToolStripMenuItem.Click

        Me.Close()
        frmBOMSteel.MdiParent = frmParent
        frmBOMSteel.Show()
        frmBOMSteel.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End Sub

    Private Sub NonSteelToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NonSteelToolStripMenuItem.Click

        Me.MdiParent = frmParent
        Me.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub WeightsRevisionsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WeightsRevisionsToolStripMenuItem.Click

        Me.Close()
        frmBOMWeightsRevisions.MdiParent = frmParent
        frmBOMWeightsRevisions.Show()
        frmBOMWeightsRevisions.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        frmModalNewItem.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FItemTypeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FItemTypeComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged

        Me.FItemNameComboBox.Text = ""

        Dim selected As Object = Me.FItemTypeComboBox.SelectedItem

        If (TypeOf selected Is DataRowView) Then

            Dim row As DataRow = DirectCast(selected, DataRowView).Row
            Dim fItemType As String = CStr(row.Item("fItemType"))
            Dim view As New DataView(DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems)

            view.RowFilter = String.Format("[fItemType]='{0}'", fItemType)
            Me.FItemNameComboBox.DataSource = view.ToTable(True, "fItemName")
            Me.FItemNameComboBox.DisplayMember = "fItemName"

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TblItemsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TblItemsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TblItemsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TblItemsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TblItemsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TblItemsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click_2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TblItemsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset)

    End Sub
End Class
```

---

The following is the code for my Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblItems] (
    [fItemID]     INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [fItemName]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [fItemType]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [fItemModel]  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [fItemWeight] INT          NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([fItemID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Do you use AutoGenerateColumn or you add columns manually?

Comment: I need to make **fItemID** add generate a number automatically, but it does not seem to work either... right now, every item is added manually.

Comment: _add more then 10 characters to fItemWeight_ = characters? This number field. Can not get over the [Upper limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) of the integer type = int32 .

Comment: I mean numbers to _fItemWeight_, not Characters. And I do not understand the article you linked me to.

Comment: set all setting in datatable level. for generate a number automaticall use DataTableName.Columns("")..AutoIncrement = True. and set in DataGridViewName.AutoGenerateColumns, then set DataGridViewName.DataSource = DataTableName.

Comment: Can you explain a little more, I can't understand your grammar. I'm sorry.

Comment: You'll have to find a column named "name", we can't find it for you.  Look for a foreign key constraint.  The error for fItemWeight is obvious, an *int* can never have more than 10 characters, "2147483647" is the maximum value you can store in an int.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: That makes more sense. I do apologize, when I showed the column name as 'Name' I was implying that it used the name in the error message/ so when I try to put 11 characters / numbers in *fItemType* I get: _Cannot set Column 'name'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column._ Does that make sense?

Comment: @Neolisk, I will Edit my post to show all the code for the form and for the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that your adapters are *not* in sync with the database. You could try remapping or you could try appending this within the load method:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems.Columns("fItemName").MaxLength = 50
    Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems.Columns("fItemType").MaxLength = 50
    Me.DbStarFliteSystemsDataset.tblItems.Columns("fItemModel").MaxLength = 50
    '.....
End Sub
```

**Remapping**

When you add a DB (database) to your project VS (Visual Studio) creates a strongly typed in-memory cache representing the data. This enables you to use a `DataSet` in your application with the same schema as your DB. However, if the DB schema changes afterwards (e.g. you have changed a type/length/name of a column), the cache is **not** updated. In the "Solution Explorer" pane there should be a file named `[NameOfDB]DataSet.xsd`. Double-clicking this file will open an editor allowing you to edit the DS and all its tables. Ensure it reflects the updated DB schema - close - save - rebuild.

Comment: The problem with this is that now, I can add the Data, but it does not save it after the form is closed... So how would I remap this?

Comment: I was assuming that you'd created a "Entity Data Model" of the database or at least parts of it. Right?

Comment: I linked the table to the DataGridView by simply dragging it to the form from the Data Sources pane.

Comment: Were the table schema generated by Visual Studio or did you create it yourself?

Comment: Also, I created a new form, and added the table to it, and it is still giving the same errors.

Comment: Hm.. I'm using VS 2010.. You must somehow remap/update your adapters/dataset/datatables (which is generated by VS), to match the database. But i'm sorry to say that I don't know how to do this in VS 2013:/

Comment: How would you do it in 2010?

Comment: Take a close look at [this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8oc1j4dipzltte/20660286.jpg). The inset is the original table. But as you can see, after I delete column "Category Name" the typed dataset still contains it. And I can still refer to the column "t.Category_NameColumn" though it doesn't exist in the db. If I now tried to update that table it would throw an error. Same if I changed field type/length etc. This is what I believe has happend. In VS 2010 i can modify a .xsd file (the typed dataset). Look at [this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wv323gz4t4ientw/20660286-2.jpg).

Comment: AHA! That is what I was looking for. I am still new at this, but that set me up for success. I can change the MaxLength [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5124101/Typed%20Dataset.png)

Comment: Excellent! If this was the issue please report and I will update the answer and be more specific about the phrase "remapping".

Comment: It was. Apparently, even though I do not think I did it exactly... right... but I opened the .XSD file and just changed the MaxLength properties and it worked. Once I see you redo the answer, I will upvote and mark it as the solution. :) Thank you again.

Comment: Good! I'll do it tomorrow, need to get some sleep:p

Comment: It didn't work for me until I exited Visual Studio and came back in. Rebuilt and worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for those struggling with a similar issue:

I resolved this by simply deleting the dataset out of the project explorer and re-adding it via the "Add New Data Source" option in the project menu. As long as you don't delete the table references that sit at the bottom of the form editor, you're databindings will be OK.

When you re-add the dataset, it must be called the exact same name as the one you had before you deleted it. If done correctly, any edited columns in the database will now be back in sync.

Answer (score 0):

**in the first time you need change the maxlength in your table from DB

try this ( in -VS 2010-)

Go to Solution Explorer

click right on 'YourFile'.xsd/ open

Search & click right on the Column name in conflict

Properties

change MaxLength to your need

Save